# "Validation Error: Password can't be blank" but no password field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, devise, passwords

I have a form to save information to a database for my website.  Even though the form does not require a sign in, whenever I try to submit the form, I get an error "Validation failed: Password can't be blank".  I'm not sure why this is happening as there is no password field in the form.  Here is the code from the controller, the error is from the save line:

```
def create
    @newinstructor = Instructor.new
    @newinstructor_app = InstructorApp.where(first_name: params['instructor']['first_name']).where(last_name: params['instructor']['last_name'])
    @newinstructor.first_name = params['instructor']['first_name']
    @newinstructor.last_name = params['instructor']['last_name']
    @newinstructor.story = params['instructor']['story']
    @newinstructor.save!
```

Here is the instructor.rb:

```
 class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :activities

      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :activities
      has_one :instructor_app
    end
```

Comment: fyi it's easier to read if you edit your original post with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fix, by following either of the following approaches:

Remove the `:validatable` option from your `Instructor`, devise option should now be:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
```

OR

add the following method to your `Instructor`

```
def password_required?
 false
end
```

Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Devise modules like `:database_authenticatable` in your instructor model.  You cant see it but Devise expects there to be a password field by default.  If there's no login for your instructor form then one option is to simply delete the devise modules.  Devise is generally used for the User model if you have one, to authenticate when a user initially signs up and/or logs in